socket.io server on mobile not working How to fix it I replaced localhost with my desktop ip also but still not working. how to fix it?
client:
import { createContext, useContext, useMemo } from "react";
import socketClient from "socket.io-client";

const SocketContext = createContext(null);
 

export const SocketProvider = (props) => {  
  const socket = socketClient('http://localhost:5000')
 
  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
      {props.children} 
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useSocket = () => {
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
  return socket;
};


I replaced localhost with device ip still not working.
This is the server side code
server:
const {Server} = require('socket.io')


const io = new Server(5000, {
    cors:true
})
 
const emailToSocketIdMap =  new Map()
const socketIdToEmailMap =  new Map()


io.on("connection", (socket)=>{ 
    console.log('connection establised')
    socket.on("room:join", (data)=>{
        const {roomId, email} = data
        console.log(roomId)
        socket.emit("room:join", data)
        socket.join(roomId)
        socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user:joined', {email, id:socket.id})
        socket.on("call:user", (data)=>{
            const {offer, id} = data
            socket.to(id).emit("incoming:call", {offer, from:socket.id})
        })
        socket.on('call:accepted', (data)=>{
           const {answer, to} = data
           socket.to(to).emit("call:accepted", {answer, from:socket.id})
        })

        
    })
})



it was working on desktop but on the mobile browser
homepage of the app shows a form with two input field email, roomId, and a join Button when join on the desktop it redirects me to the room page,  but there is no response on the mobile
